# how to delete div if resource object is empty

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating an online listing/directory of organizations which displays on a web page. Each listing has the `org's name`, `state`, `'website link'`, `'training calendar' link`, etc. The information that feeds the directory comes from an xml file that I export from an excel file.

I have a `datastructure.js` file that defines my resource objects and loads it from my xml. Then I have a different `script.js` files that generates the results on the web page formatted as Bootstrap 3 panels. All of this part works fine.

This is what the js looks like for creating the panels:

```
// generate resource table based on selected filters
function generateResults(state) {
    var table = $('#LibraryResults');
    // first clear the table
    table.empty();
    // next generate items matching filters
        $.each(resource_list, function(i, e) {
            if (state == "" || state == e.state ) {
                // block div panel
                var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                iDiv.id = 'column'+i;
                iDiv.className = 'panel panel-primary';
                document.getElementById('LibraryResults').appendChild(iDiv);

                // heading panel
                var innerDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv1.id = 'heading'+i;
                innerDiv1.className = 'panel-heading';
                iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv1); 

                // body panel
                var innerDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv2.id = 'body'+i;
                innerDiv2.className = 'panel-body';
                iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv2);

                // training calendar div
                var trainDiv = document.createElement('div');
                trainDiv.id = 'train'+i;
                trainDiv.className = 'col-sm-3 col-xs-6';
                innerDiv2.appendChild(trainDiv);

                //I want these items to go inside the trainDiv
                    $(trainDiv).append( 
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span> <a href='" + e.urltrain + "' target='_blank'>Training Calendar</a>"
                    );
                }
            });
    }
```

My challenge:

Some of the information the organizations provide is optional, so I may have an empty field in my xmls data (i.e. resource object 'urltrain' is empty). Consequently, the `'training calendar' link` in `trainDiv` has an empty href.

What I want to do is, if a resource `object (urltrain)` is empty I want to remove the impacted`div (trainDiv)` and its contents.

I am pretty novice when it comes to javascript. I can replicate code with some tweaks for my new needs, but I don't know enough about the language to create something new.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to do this is, you can set the property of the div (display: none) or another way is to simply remove the div element from the DOM.

Comment: So after looking closely to your code, you can put an if condition just before creating trainDiv and check if e.urltrain is not empty then only create this div else don't create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below. I added an if condition, that will conditionally add the div. Let me know if this works, else i can modify the solution to fit your use case.

```
// generate resource table based on selected filters
function generateResults(state) {
    var table = $('#LibraryResults');
    // first clear the table
    table.empty();
    // next generate items matching filters
    $.each(resource_list, function(i, e) {
        if (state == "" || state == e.state ) {
            // block div panel
            var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
            iDiv.id = 'column'+i;
            iDiv.className = 'panel panel-primary';
            document.getElementById('LibraryResults').appendChild(iDiv);

            // heading panel
            var innerDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
            innerDiv1.id = 'heading'+i;
            innerDiv1.className = 'panel-heading';
            iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv1); 

            // body panel
            var innerDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
            innerDiv2.id = 'body'+i;
            innerDiv2.className = 'panel-body';
            iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv2);

            // training calendar div
            if(e.urltrain != ""){
              var trainDiv = document.createElement('div');
              trainDiv.id = 'train'+i;
              trainDiv.className = 'col-sm-3 col-xs-6';
              innerDiv2.appendChild(trainDiv);
               //I want these items to go inside the trainDiv
                $(trainDiv).append( 
                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span> <a href='" + e.urltrain + "' target='_blank'>Training Calendar</a>"
                );
            }



            }
        });
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was also able to replicate it for all of my optional items. Thank you so much!